# SQL Server Stored Procedure Execution timeout - Do I need additional indexes?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I've inherited the following SQL Server stored procedure (on Azure SQL Server):

```
PROCEDURE [Sources].[DeleteRawCaptures]
    (@SourceId BIGINT,
     @Count INT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ROWCOUNT 500

    DECLARE @BatchId uniqueidentifier

    SELECT @BatchId = CaptureBatch
    FROM [Data].[RawCaptures]
    WHERE CaptureId = (SELECT MAX(CaptureId)
                       FROM [Data].[RawCaptures]
                       WHERE SourceId = @SourceId)

    DELETE FROM [Data].[RawCaptures] 
    WHERE SourceId = @SourceId
      AND CaptureBatch <> @BatchId

    SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

After many months of this working without issue, it is timing out as of late.  The former developer who built the solution, in the brief moment I was able to contact him, suggested it's possible there may be an additional index needed on the Data.RawCaptures table, as the last time he ran into errors many months ago, he needed to add another index.  He was not any more specific than that, unfortunately.

I'm not well-versed enough in SQL Server indexes to determine what type of index, and on what columns, I should ensure I have in place, to be certain the above stored procedure is running at it's optimal ability.

These are the indexes that *are* currently in place:

[image]

Just to clarify in case the title of the index does not give enough information:

- The first one's fields are `CaptureBatch` and `Status`
- The second one's field is `CaptureDateTime`
- The third one's fields are `SourceId` and `CaptureBatch`
- The fourth one's fields are `SourceId` and `Status`
- The fifth one's field is `SourceId`
- The sixth one's field is`Status`
- The seventh one's fields are `Status` and `CaptureDateTime`

Just FYI, there are two other stored procedures that relate to this process and contain the other fields above that don't appear in the stored procedure that I've posted.

The amount of data in Data.RawCaptures is beginning to increase exponentially. Because of this, I am wondering if I need yet another index for this table (perhaps even of a different type?) or if what I already have should have me well-covered. If the latter is the case, I will start investigating other avenues to determine the cause of the timeouts.

Unfortunately SQL Server Profile is not supported in Azure SQL Database.  I'll need to discover another approach.

The Query Execution Plan here:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJk4pHiw7

Comment: Use [the profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler) to find out which part of the query causes the slowdown.

Comment: @Stijn thanks but The Profiler is not supported by Azure SQL Database

Comment: Without an execution plan, there's not a lot we can help with. [This might help](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: Thanks, @DavidG I have now added it to my post.

Comment: You've given us the execution plan for creating the procedure, not for running it :)

Comment: Shoot, I'm sorry, I'm new to this as you can see.  Let me try this again...

Comment: Since data "increase exponentially", and since you run this on a regular basis (daily or weekly or monthly), then trim the data that you have already looked at on a previous run (prior to yesterday, last week, last month).  Add  WHERE CaptureDateTime > some prior run...   There is no sense in re-analyzing old data that has already been taken care of.  Noone is Inserting data with stale or old CaptureDateTime.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this - it would help to understand why you think it should be closed.  This issue has basically stopped our Production in its tracks.  This post is not a frivolous waste of space on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidG I'm getting an error when trying to paste the Query Execution Plan in the Brent Ozar site ("The supplied XML is not a valid SQL Server query plan xml"). I have copied it directly out of SSMS, so I would have to disgree.  I have the Plan though - is there some other manner or some other site I can post it?

Comment: You could put it on https://pastebin.com/ perhaps or https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @DavidG thanks, that's perfect.  Link added to the post.

Comment: Well that tells us that it's the `DELETE` that is slow and not the `SELECT` (it takes 99% of the total cost.) And inside that, the clustered index delete is the major part, 84% of that batch. Not really sure why that is so slow, but you would expect that to be the majority of the execution time. 500 records isn't a lot though. Is the table quite fragmented perhaps? Lots of inserts and deletes will do that. As an aside, guessing from the table name, I don't see a need to have a clustered index on there.

Comment: Can the inclusion of a non-necessary clustered index impede performance?  If so, I can certainly get rid of it.

Comment: @DavidG, see the following link regarding table fragmentation.  Thoughts?  Not sure how to interpret this:  https://imgur.com/a/ONPOEnk

Comment: Update - upon researching the fragmentation percentages, I'm rebuilding all my indexes now.

Comment: Yeah, that's huge fragmentation!

Comment: My fingers are crossed as tight as I've ever crossed them that rebuilding these indexes does the trick :)

Comment: @DavidG by the way regarding the clustered index, this is the PK index that was auto-created with the table and therefore SQL Server will not allow me to get rid of it even if I wanted to.

Comment: Well let's hope the re-indexing fixes your problem, if it does, I'll write that as an answer. Also, I spoke to Brent Ozar and figured out why your execution plan didn't work (it's a known bug) and managed to get it through. I've updated the question with the fixed link.

Comment: Not sure if this is still going but....can you expan on "After many months of this working without issue, it is timing out as of late" - what is the profile of the timing. Did it just get longer and longer over time? Or did it suddenly go from fast to really slow? This type of analysis helps in understanding the issue

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid great to see you here.  This happened suddenly.  After months of a "well-oiled machine" populating our search index with new records every 24 hours, I noticed that the index hadn't received any new records for over 72 hours.  When I investigated the index queue, I discovered hundreds of Execution timeout errors.  The errors pointed to the Stored Procedure mentioned in the post.  Whether it got longer over time, I can't say for sure, but, as mentioned, our indexing process was running fine until it stopped taking in new records as I mentioned (which happened a few days ago).

Comment: @DavidG thanks for pasting the query plan to brentozar.com!!  Not sure why I couldn't get it to work!

Comment: When a stored procedure that takes parameters is suddenly _really_ slow, it is often parameter sniffing / stale plans. Read this for more info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462312/sql-server-stored-procedure-suddenly-become-slow Adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` often fixes it but you should do some more detailed background reading to understand further.

Comment: @DavidG - the execution timeouts did not subside after rebuilding the indexes.  As a temporary fix and to get my system up from being at a screeching halt, I ended up manually running the SP query and passing every single sourceid parameter, manually.  It took hours, but I got through all of them.  I will have to dig really deep to figure out what's going on here. I suppose a new thread may be in order once I have more details.  Thanks for all your help - I'm sure rebuilding those indexes was very much necessary anyway!